# Run a program with elevated rights and with arguments

Tags: command-line

in a elevated cmd i run this and it works fine
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\RegAsm.exe" /tlb PromatieScheduler.dll"

but i need to run it as a batch file, i tried this

```
powershell Start-Process -FilePath cmd.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\regasm.exe" /tlb promatieScheduler.dll
```

But it will not add the arguments in the newly opend elevated cmd box

Comment: i need to run it as administrator cmd for it to work
dit opens the new cmd as admin but does not run the correct command
powershell Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\regasm.exe", -ArgumentList "/tlb, promatieScheduler.dll"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think powershell is necessary here. It offers to benefit and it only makes things more complicated. All you need to do is create a `.bat` file with the following content:

```
runas /user:administrator "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\regasm.exe" /tlb promatieScheduler.dll
```

Comment: I need to run it with elevated admin rights
cmd.exe -Verb RunAs

Comment: cmd has the same function, which is the command `runas`, see updated answer.